# Update in real time fill_color in Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, plot, bokeh

I'm trying to update `fill_color` from a real time `hex_tile` plot in bokeh 2.3.3 in python 3.8. More specifically, I want to update the max range of the linear_cmap that fill the plot. To update the max value, I've tried to pass a linear mapper to a column in the ColumnDataSource that I'm using. I've also tried to use .update over the figure, and pass the mapper to fill_color:

```
def update():
    new_data = bin_generate().to_dict(orient='list')
    source.stream(new_data,rollover = 50)
    maper = linear_cmap('counts', 'Viridis256', 0, max(bin_generate().counts))
    f.hex_tile.fill_color=maper
    #f.hex_tile.fill_color={'transform':maper}

data=bin_generate().to_dict(orient='list')
maper = linear_cmap('counts', 'Viridis256', 0, max(bin_generate().counts))

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)
f = figure(x_range=(-5,5),y_range=(0,6), toolbar_location=None, tools="hover",
         match_aspect=True, background_fill_color='#440154')

f.hex_tile(q="q", r="r",size=0.09, line_color=None, source=source,  
           fill_color=maper)

curdoc().add_root(f)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update,100)
```

How can I update the max value of the cmaper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't test it out but this could work :

first, give a name

```
hextile = f.hex_tile(q="q", r="r",size=0.09, line_color=None, source=source,  
           fill_color=maper)
```

in function, add :

```
hextile.glyph.fill_color=maper
```

you should check it out first from [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/hex_tile.html)

also, you should give full code and some data to check it out.